# why my click function not working in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

## Imported all the driver and library

```
    from lib2to3.pgen2.driver import Driver
    from sqlite3 import Timestamp
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from time import sleep
    import getpass as gp
```

## click function not working tweeter site not being logging with username

```
PATH = "/Users/pratikbhattarai/Downloads/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
    
    sleep(3)
    username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='text']")
    username.send_keys("LearnereaBot")
    next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Next')]")
    next_button.click()


    
    UserTags = []
    Timestamp = []
    Tweets = []
    Reply = []
    reTweets = []
    Likes = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use explicit waits, rather than implicit. The following code will wait for the elements in page to become available, input your username, and click on Next button. Do not forget to import WebDriverWait and expected_conditions:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

[...]
url='https://twitter.com/login'
browser.get(url)
username = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='text']")))
username.send_keys("LearnereaBot")
next_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Next')]")))
next_button.click()
[...]
```